# XML file is overwritten in each run

Tags: c#, xml, selenium

I am trying to write some data into XML file. 
Actually, I can do that, but in each run, the XML file is overwritten while I want it to add another row. 
This is what I have done so far:

```
  public static void StoreCustomerIntoXML(string Id)
    {

        string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
        string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
        string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;
        string reportPath = projectPath + "Customers\\CustomersListCreated.xml";


        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Customers");
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        XmlNode userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Id");
        userNode.InnerText = Id;
        rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);

       xmlDoc.Save(reportPath);

    }
```

So calling the method for the first time will include Id = 1234
and the second run will include Id = 6543
The XML file will always include the Id of last run and only this Id.

Comment: each time that you call `StoreCustomerIntoXml` method, you're creating new xml file (on the line `XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();`)

Comment: that's the problem , but what can I do inside the method in order to avoid it and add a new row instead of create a new file?

Comment: Initialize `xmlDoc` outside of `StoreCustomerIntoXml` method and pass it as parameter.

Comment: It is common to use xml format when creating log files.  Normally non-standard xml is created.  Standard xml has only one root tag.  With log files you end up with multiple tags at root level.  To make a standard xml file you would have to add new data before closing tag which is not simple.  So most people just use the non-standard format with multiple tags at root level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void StoreCustomerIntoXML(string Id)
    {

        string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
        string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
        string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;
        string reportPath = projectPath + "CustomersListCreated.xml";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        if (File.Exists(reportPath))
        {
            xmlDoc.Load(reportPath);
            XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
            XmlElement elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Id");
            elem.InnerText = Id;
            rootNode.AppendChild(elem);
        }
        else
        {                
            XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Customers");
            xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
            XmlNode userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Id");
            userNode.InnerText = Id;
            rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);
        }   
        xmlDoc.Save(reportPath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the file exists and load it using the method [Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx), instead of creating a new one every time you call your method.

```
public static void StoreCustomerIntoXML(string Id)
{    
        string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
        string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
        string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;
        string reportPath = projectPath + "Customers\\CustomersListCreated.xml";


        XmlDocument xmlDoc;
        if (File.Exists(reportPath))             
             xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reportPath); 
        else
             xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Customers");
        xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

        XmlNode userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Id");
        userNode.InnerText = Id;
        rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);

       xmlDoc.Save(reportPath);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void StoreCustomerIntoXML(string Id)
 { 
     string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
     string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
     string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;
     string reportPath = projectPath + "Customers\\CustomersListCreated.xml";

     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     XmlNode rootNode;

     if (File.Exists(reportPath)) 
     {
         xmlDoc.Load(reportPath);
         rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
     }
     else
     {
         rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Customers");
         xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
     }


     XmlNode userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Id");
     userNode.InnerText = Id;
     rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);

     xmlDoc.Save(reportPath);

 }
```